# Lotus Notes automation Error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, lotus-notes

I have some code that will forward emails for me based on the email addresses provided in a worksheet. It works fine but sometimes it will get the error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

```
Public Sub Forward_Email(findSubjectLike As String, forwardToEmailAddresses As String)

    Dim NSession As Object
    Dim NMailDb As Object
    Dim NViewObj As Variant
    Dim NInboxView As Object
    Dim NDocument As Object
    Dim NUIWorkspace As Object
    Dim NUIDocument As Object
    Dim NFwdUIDocument As Object
    
    
    Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
    Set NMailDb = NSession.CurrentDatabase
    Set NUIWorkspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

   For Each NViewObj In NMailDb.Views
        If NViewObj.IsFolder And NViewObj.Name = "($Inbox)" Then
            Set NInboxView = NViewObj
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

   
    Set NDocument = Find_Document(NInboxView, findSubjectLike)
    
    If Not NDocument Is Nothing Then
   

       
        Set NUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.EditDocument(False, NDocument)
        Sleep 1000
        NUIDocument.Forward
       
   
       
        Set NFwdUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.CurrentDocument
       
       
        NFwdUIDocument.GoToField "To"
        Sleep 200
        NFwdUIDocument.InsertText forwardToEmailAddresses
       
        
        NFwdUIDocument.GoToField "Body"
        NFwdUIDocument.Import "HTML File", "HTML DIRECTORY"
        NFwdUIDocument.InsertText vbLf
        
       
        NFwdUIDocument.Send
        NFwdUIDocument.Close

       
        Do
            Set NUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.CurrentDocument
            Sleep 200
            DoEvents
        Loop While NUIDocument Is Nothing
        Sleep 1000
        NUIDocument.Close
       
    Else
   
        MsgBox vbCrLf & findSubjectLike & vbCrLf & "not found in Inbox"

    End If
   
    Set NUIDocument = Nothing
    Set NFwdUIDocument = Nothing
    Set NDocument = Nothing
    Set NMailDb = Nothing
    Set NUIWorkspace = Nothing
    Set NSession = Nothing
   
End Sub

Private Function Find_Document(NView As Object, findSubjectLike As String) As Object

    Dim NThisDoc As Object
    Dim thisSubject As String
   
    Set Find_Document = Nothing
   
    Set NThisDoc = NView.GetFirstDocument
    While Not NThisDoc Is Nothing And Find_Document Is Nothing
        thisSubject = NThisDoc.GetItemValue("Subject")(0)
        If LCase(thisSubject) = LCase(findSubjectLike) Then Set Find_Document = NThisDoc
        Set NThisDoc = NView.GetNextDocument(NThisDoc)
    Wend

End Function
```

The issue line specifically it states as:

```
NUIDocument.Close
```

Initially I had assumed it was because certain functions weren't executing as the previous functions weren't complete. And more so because it was stating the .Close function as the perpetrator but even after adding a sleep to slow it down it still brings up the error periodically.

Comment: You really should try to do this without using any of the NotesUI classes. Those classes are using OLE automation, so everything is going through the Notes client code. Solutions based on this approach have proven (for more than 20 years) to be less stable than solutions based on the COM classes i i.e., Lotus.NotesSession instead of Notes.NotesSession - with no UI. The OLE code is literally driving the Notes UI, and anything that happens in the Notes client simultaneously while you are running your code can cause a problem.

Comment: Would you happen to know of any resources for learning more about COM classes in VB. The above code is something put together from various bits of knowledge and self taught information so changing to COM is going to be difficult when I don't have a great understanding of it.

Comment: You will start with Lotus.NotesSession. You will open the mailbox database with NotesSession.GetDatabase instead of NotesUIWorkspace.CurrentDatabsae. Your code for dealing with the inbox folder and your FindDocument will be the same. You will not use EditDocument or Forward or GotoFField.

Comment: You will use NotesDocument.GetFirstItem and/or ReplaceItemValues calls to update header fields. You will use NotesStream to read the HTML file. For the Body field, ypu will use either the NotesRichTextItem class and its various methods or the NotesMIMEEntity class and its methods. And you will use NotesDocument.Send instead of NotesUIDocument.Send.

Comment: As far as resources go, there are a few dozen books that have been written about Lotus Notes development. All of them (since 1995) will have discussions of the LotusScript back end classes, which are the same as the COM classes, with just a few exceptions - e.g., that COM has to initialize a session differently.  And the best resource is simply reading the documentation for the classes that I mentioned, searching (here on StackOverflow or on your favorite search engine) for examples using those classes, and asking questions here that are specific to problems you may encounter with them.